# Neko Dlls in Haxe C++ target

Tags: c++, haxe

I am trying to use Neko dlls (written in C++) with the C++ target of Haxe. I am able to call the functions in haxe but not able to pass values.

This is the C++ code -

```
value Hello(value h)
{
    cout << val_int(h);
    return val_int(1);
}DEFINE_PRIM(Hello, 1);
```

This is the Haxe code -

```
class Main
{
     var load = cpp.Lib.loadLazy( "ndll" , "Hello", 1 );
     static function main()
     {
          load(1);
     }
 }
```

It executes only if the function does not take parameters. Also, the value that is returned form the C++ function to Haxe is `null`.

This code actually works perfectly when I compile for the neko target, but it doesn't seem to work with the cpp target.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you'll have to add to the header of your cpp file:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_API
#include <hx/CFFI.h>
```

(instead of neko's headers)
If you want the ndll to run on both neko and hxcpp, you should also add

```
#define NEKO_COMPATIBLE
```

before the hx/CFFI.h include.

You can compile using whatever is best for you, but I recommend using a Build.xml to generate your ndll, since it will automatically add the include and lib paths correctly for hxcpp's headers. You can see an example of a very simple Build.xml here:
http://pastebin.com/X9rFraYp

You can see more documentation about hxcpp's CFFI here: http://haxe.org/doc/cpp/ffi

Comment: thank for the answer. but, could you explain a little bit more about how to compile with build.xml.

Comment: The Build.xml reference is a bit sparse at the moment. You can find some examples in the [NME](http://www.haxenme.org/) project. To compile with a Build.xml file, use `haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the fully corrected C++ code :

```
#define IMPLEMENT_API

/* Will be compatible with Neko on desktop targets. */
#if defined(HX_WINDOWS) || defined(HX_MACOS) || defined(HX_LINUX)
    #define NEKO_COMPATIBLE
#endif

#include <hx/CFFI.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Your hello function. */
value hello(value h)
{
    printf("%i\n", val_int(h));
    return alloc_int(1);
}
DEFINE_PRIM(hello, 1);

/* Main entry point. */
extern "C" void mylib_main()
{
    // Initialization code goes here
}
DEFINE_ENTRY_POINT(mylib_main);
```

What's important is that every value given as an argument to a primitive or returned by a primitive must be of the type `value`. That's why your parameter and return didn't work.

`val_int` is used to convert a `value` into a native C type, so your printing code was correct. But your return was wrong : you can't return a C `int` type when the function expects you to return a `value` to Haxe. You need to create a new Haxe `Int` type and return it. This is done with the help of `alloc_int`.

Here's the Haxe part of the code as a reference :

```
class Main
{
    static var hello = cpp.Lib.load("myLib", "hello", 1);

    static function main()
    {
        var myReturnedInt:Int = hello(1);
    }
}
```

A few helpful links :

- [Neko C FFI](http://nekovm.org/doc/ffi)
- [Neko FFI tutorial](http://haxe.org/doc/neko/ffi)
- [CPP FFI notes](http://haxe.org/doc/cpp/ffi)

Comment: cool. this is what i was looking for. you have given an expanded form of what Waneck has given. thanks