# Opening and using DLL created with HXCPP

Tags: haxe, hxcpp

I successfully (hopefully) have created a DLL using HXCPP, however I am having a hard time trying to open and use it with an HXCPP application.
I tried using [this](https://github.com/R3D9477/haxe-basics/tree/master/5_Backends/5.1_CPP/5.1.2_SharedLibraryWithTest/5.1.2.1_DllWithMainEP), and it works for the DLL (Lib/), but for the Test App (LibTestApp/) I get the error "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dlfcn.h': No such file or directory", but I cannot for the life of me find it anywhere.
Plus, that example only shows how the Main.main function is called, and nothing else, which clearly is not too useful.

Anyone knows anything about all this?

Comment: Are you testing this in Windows? `dlfcn.h` and `dlopen()`, used in your reference, are unix-related, so they will work in Mac and Linux but not Windows.

Comment: @Giuppe 
Oh, I guess that explains the issue I'm having. Yes, I am on Windows. Do you know what their equivalents/substitutes are on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to `dlopen()` in Windows should be LoadLibrary: [Dynamically load a function from a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll)

However keep in mind that [building a DLL using C++ can be pretty unmanageable](https://github.com/snowkit/hxcpp-guide/blob/master/work-in-progress/build/5.0-building-a-dynamic-library-from-hxcpp.md) so in that case you should [(manually) write a C wrapper](https://github.com/snowkit/hxcpp-guide/blob/master/work-in-progress/build/5.1-building-a-wrapped-dynamic-library.md).

A simplified way, if you don't need your dll to be compatible with other non-haxe windows programs, is to [write an NDLL instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417589/neko-dlls-in-haxe-c-target). NDLLs work for every platform supported by the C++ and Neko target, so (for example) you don't need to write a separate .dll for windows and a .so for mac.

Comment: ouuhh this is all so confusing, i think i'll stop looking into this for now.
but thank you for your time and help, i appreciate that. wish i could vote it